# How to sign an end of parameter line in windows cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe

I have a program, named IsCmdBld.exe, which is doing some job for me.
The problem is, when I'm trying to redirect its output to the log file on a disk, the program can't determine the end of the parameter line.

Example:

```
"IsCmdBld.exe" -p param1 -tparam2 -sparam3 > "log.txt"
```

Result:

```
IsCmdBld error: the parameter " > "log.txt" " is not preceded by a switch.
```

Is there any way to circumvent such a problem?

Comment: try putting an ampersand in after the trailing argument.

Comment: @FrankThomas, nada, same result.

Comment: then try a semicolon. from what I'm seeing here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true a semicolon will "end" a parameter.

Comment: Weird, in a _CmdLine-Parser_ (or _BatchLine-Parser_ as well) that `>` redirector should split the command line in such way that rest of line including `>` will not be passed to program called... But previous parameters: does anyone contain an unquoted sign with special meaning in `cmd`, e.g. `"`, `^`, `&`, `|`, `<`, `>`, `(`, `)`, `%` or `!`? However, maybe your `IsCmdBld.exe` program allows a parameter (switch) which could enable creating a verbose process log file?

Answer (score 0):

Write a batch script, name it e.g. `icb.bat` and instead of `IsCmdBld` launch `icb`:

```
icb -p param1 -tparam2 -sparam3 > "log.txt"
```

The script could be a follows:

```
:: icb.bat begin

"IsCmdBld.exe" %*

@goto :eof
:: icb.bat end
```

If used in a script already, then bring to bear next block syntax with parentheses:

```
:: some code
(
  "IsCmdBld.exe" -p param1 -tparam2 -sparam3
) > "log.txt"
:: another code
```

Comment: the problem is not actual anymore but thank you for your effort :)